# Get place_id of a specific address component

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

```
var autocomplete;

function initialize() {
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
            types: ['address']
        });
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
        fillInAddress();
    });
}

function fillInAddress() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    /* need to get the neighborhood place_id here */
}
```

My `place` object is a full address and what I need is the `place_id` for a specific component of this address: the `neighborhood`.

I tried to make a reverse-geocoding using the `latlng` of my `place` object and filtering by `neighborhood` (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=xxx,yyy&result_type=neighborhood), but it returns multiple results and eventually multiple (and incorrect) neighborhoods.

Is there anyway to get the `place_id` of the neighborhood?

Comment: `place.place_id` doesn't work?

Comment: I need the place_id of a component of this place -- my place is an address, and what I need is the place_id of this address' neighborhood.

Comment: Just echoing that it's really annoying that this isn't provided with the initial API response. For some of the address components (e.g. cities) it's clear that they do have their own placeids....

Comment: Did you solve it eventually? I'm looking for exactly the same thing in the geocoding API (where you get the same components structure, missing place_ids).

I'm about to identify components using its long_name and types array, but it just feels wrong, when you should have a place_id.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you're trying to accomplish: this returns the Full Autocomplete Search Result, Place ID, Lat, Lng, and Formatted address but you can modify it to return any Address Components (or remove any unneeded ones) into `form inputs`.

```
var placeSearch;
var componentForm = {
    street_number: 'long_name',
    place_id: 'long_name'
};

var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.877461, -87.638085),
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    scrollwheel: false,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    streetViewControl: false,
    panControl: false
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
mapOptions);

var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
(
document.getElementById('field_autocomplete'));

var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
});

google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
    infowindow.close();
    marker.setVisible(false);

    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    if (!place.geometry) {
        window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
        return;
    }

    // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
        map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
        map.setZoom(12); // Why 17? Because it looks good.
    }
    marker.setIcon( /** @type {google.maps.Icon} */ ({
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(25, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50)
    }));
    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    marker.setVisible(true);

    var address = '';
    if (place.address_components) {
        address = [
        (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''), (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''), (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')].join(' ');
    }

    infowindow.setContent('<div id="infowindow"><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + 'Place ID: ' + place.place_id + '<br>' +
    place.formatted_address);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
});

google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
    fillInAddress();
});

function fillInAddress() {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    document.getElementById('place_id').value = place.place_id;
    document.getElementById('latitude').value = place.geometry.location.lat();
    document.getElementById('longitude').value = place.geometry.location.lng();

    var formatted_address = place.formatted_address;
    document.getElementById("formatted_address").value = formatted_address;

    for (var component in componentForm) {
        document.getElementById(component).value = '';
        document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }

    // Get each component of the address from the place details
    // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
        var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
        if (componentForm[addressType]) {
            var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
            document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
        }
    }
}

// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
            position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

            var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

            document.getElementById('latitude').value = latitude;
            document.getElementById('longitude').value = longitude;

            autocomplete.setBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(geolocation, geolocation));
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: No, that's not I want. I already have the full search results for an address, and what I need is the place_id of the neighborhood of this address (and not only its name).